# PostgreSQL & DataMapper issues

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql, sinatra

Been scratching my head for a while on this one and despite trying many variations I cannot see the mistake. After writing the app file, which contains what looks like the correct DataMapper.setup code for using PostgreSQL (?), and upon trying to play around in IRB/PRY, i just get a 'FATAL database not created' message even after i have called 'Song.auto_migrate!', here is my code, can anyone help me get past this? Thanks in advance:

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-core' #main DataMapper gem
require 'dm-migrations' #extra DataMapper functionality extension

DataMapper.setup(:default, "postgres://localhost/development")

class Song

  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :lyrics, Text
  property :length, Integer
  property :released_on, Date
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

I require the file all fine in irb, then call Song.auto_migrate! and it runs the 'database does not exist' error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in command line:

```
psql
```

and then

```
CREATE DATABASE development;
```

before even trying to run Data Mapper setup  code.

Comment: Thanks Vaidas n Roi. For some reason i seemed to think that auto_migrate created the database for you!! D'oh !!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing this line: DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, remember that auto_migrate! will wipe any existing data, whereas auto_upgrade! doesn't: http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html